# Threejs Texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I execute my render of some geometry I can see in my console this warning:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture is not power of two. Texture.minFilter should be set to THREE.NearestFilter or THREE.LinearFilter.
```

I can't understand the reason and the background of my canvas is completely black.

Comment: the size of your texture is not powers of two (ie. 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 ...). Set `yourTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter` to get rid of the error message.

Comment: Perfect, I solved but I can't understand why the canvas background is completely black @gaitat

Comment: there is really not enough information in the question to assert that. more code is required and maybe a jsfiddle.

Comment: I put my live code here http://www.felpone.netsons.org/. If you push test button you can see the rendering @gaitat

Comment: in chrome I see an image

Comment: Yes, but background is black right?@gaitat

Comment: it's possible that your texture has not fully loaded resulting in the texture not being power of two.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The size of your texture is not powers of two (ie. 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 ...).

Set `yourTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter` to get rid of the error message.

Comment: @marek can you post a question with your issue?

Comment: Sure. Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330626/three-js-image-is-not-power-of-two-warning