# Three.js Image is not power of two warning

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem with this warning I'm getting from three.js. The warning is: **THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (600x480). Resized to 512x512**
I have tried adding THREE.LinearFilter, but it does nothing.

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(data[i]['image']);
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            var paintingGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
            var paintingMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                map: texture
            });
            var painting = new THREE.Mesh(paintingGeometry, paintingMaterial);
```

What are your suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a problem at all. This is a very useful feature, as Three.js now resizes an image to power of two for you. Earlier, you had to do it yourself. If you want to rid this warning off, so resize your image(s) to power of two before you use them.

Comment: @prisoner849 Ok, I understand. But what if I want to use image, which has certain proportions like 600x480. How can I resize it without changing the proportions?

Comment: Three.js accepts images of power of two only.

Comment: is the resulting texturing visually wrong?

Comment: Note that if you perform the scaling yourself, you may also need to adjust your UV coordinates.

Comment: After the resizing done by Three.js, the textures looks alright. Which I don't understand why, because how could image with size 600x480 look alright when resized to 512x512?

Comment: Scaling algorithms are really good :)
But assuming you are applying the image to some kind of geometry and not just passing it through, the image is already being resampled and modified in a bunch of ways much more destructive than a 2D image scaling just to get it on the geometry. So it's not really that the image looks like it hasn't been scaled, it's that all the other transformations overwhelm the quality loss from scaling the image to power of two.

Comment: Or maybe you mean "looks alright" regarding proportion, not loss of quality from scaling, and in that case it's because three.js adjusts the UV map when it rescales your image, so it won't look stretched. What will happen is it won't cover the same area, instead resorting to a behavior like tiling/wrapping. So if your 600x480 texture was just right to cover some geometry, you'll have to choose if you want it to stretch or repeat.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a problem here - all textures need power of two images. If you're having issues with how the texture is scaled and applied to your geometry you should check out the docs for [THREE.Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture), specifically the `wrap` and `repeat` properties.

Comment: The way the original question is loading the image is correct, the loader automatically resizes the image for you and lets you know in a warning. The only reason there's even a warning is because scaling your images ahead of time would be more efficient, but reading the comments on the question indicates that the asker doesn't want to do that.

Comment: Yeah, neither do I. I have the OP's problem too, I need to render an image in webgl without resizing it, because that resize is going to interpolate the image pixels and completely destroy the fine details in it. So I was hoping to find an answer that explained how to actually load an image, instead of saying "there is no problem" when there clearly is ;)

Comment: As I've said in my answer, and as others have mentioned in the comments, the image must be power of two at some point (although this may be changing soon with WebGL 2). You can do it yourself beforehand, or let three.js do it. Regarding the interpolation destroying the image, I empathize with that concern all too well from my struggles with 3D graphics. But think of it this way - the image is going to be sampled and interpolated when applying it to a geometry anyways, and in a much more destructive manner than a simple 2D image scaling.

Comment: I'd also appreciate it if you could tone down the snideness and assume a little bit of good faith - I'm not here pushing an opinion or dismissing anyone's struggles, but trying to help others learn a few things that I've learned, but hopefully a bit more efficiently. The OP's problem and the problem you present are different - the OP wants to keep the proportions of the image, which three.js does when resizing to power of two by adjusting the UV map - why I said "no problem". Your question - not resizing the image at all, is more restrictive and runs into WebGL 1 limitations: bit.ly/2PZG3eG